# html single line textbox with read only and input

Tags: php, html

How do I add a string in the beginning of this textbox and have it as read only and then allow users to enter text ahead of it?

Here is my code:

```
<textarea style="width: 387px; height: 17px;" rows="3" class="do_input" name="job_title" cols="40"></textarea>
```

Currently it's a plain textbox you can type anything inside. 
What I want is like this: 
I WILL: demo text 
so I Will: Will be read only and greyed and user input text will be in front of it.

Comment: i believe the textarea contents has to be all editable or all not.

Comment: Why can't you just have plain text in front of it? `I WILL: <text area>`

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do with a little bit of JavaScript.

Add an id, such as`id="myTextArea"`, to the HTML for your textarea like this:

```
<textarea style="width: 387px; height: 17px;" rows="3" class="do_input" name="job_title" cols="40" id="myTextArea"></textarea>
```

Then, add the following JavaScript somewhere in your page or in the head section:

```
readOnlyString = "I WILL: "
myTextArea = document.getElementById("myTextArea");
myTextArea.value = readOnlyString;
preservedText = readOnlyString;

// Check the value only when the textarea is focused and after the user presses a key
myTextArea.onfocus = function () {
        document.onkeyup = function (e) {
                updatedText = myTextArea.value;
            if (updatedText.indexOf(readOnlyString) == -1)
            {
                    myTextArea.value = preservedText;
            }
                preservedText = myTextArea.value;
        };
};
```

You can check out the JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zh539hur/) if you want to play around with it.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is the placeholder attribute 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

and I think you're also looking for the readonly attribute
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp